# getting embedded video's URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, embed, window.location

How can I extract the URL of embedded youtube video using javascript? window.location.href gives me the URL of the page, not the embedded video.

Answer (score -1):

Get some reference to the iframe, either by setting an ID and using `getElementById` (best) or using `getElementsByTagName` and finding the right index (worst).

Then you can just get that iframe's `src` attribute.